# DropDownList not registered with any event handler is triggering a different dropdownlist's selectedindexchanged handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure why this is occurring but I have a breakpoint in the eventhandler which is only registered to dropdownlist A and every time dropdowlist B changes its selected index and causes a postback, the breakpoint is activated.

Dropdownlist B is should not have any event handlers registered to it.

Another oddity is that I created a fresh webform and simply copied the relevant code for the two dropdown lists into the new form and everything works correctly there.

What could be the reason that dropdownlist B triggers dropdownlist A's handler?

Edit:  I would post the code behind but it is fairly lengthy, even in just the relevant parts.

I did do a search for the phrase selectedIndex and I found it only in one place where I register it with the correct dropdownlist.  All of this is done programatically so the markup would not be much help.

Edit 2:

```
 DropDownList ddlname1 = new DropDownList();

                ddlname1.AutoPostBack = true;

                ddlname1.EnableViewState = true;

                ddlname1.ID = "ddlname1" + dex.ToString();
ddlname1.DataSource = nameODS1;

                ddlname1.DataValueField = "Card";

                ddlname1.DataBind();
```

These are the only lines in which ddlname1 (or dropdownlist B from the above discussion) are mentioned.

Edit 3:

```
DropDownList ddlset1 = new DropDownList();
ddlset1.ID = "ddlset1" + dex.ToString();

                ddlset1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlset_SelectedIndexChanged);

                ddlset1.AutoPostBack = true;

                ddlset1.EnableViewState = true;
ddlset1.DataSource = setODS1;

                ddlset1.DataValueField = "Set";

                ddlset1.DataBind();
```

As requested, this is the code relevant to the other dropdownlist

Edit 4:  I just noticed something else which might be relevant.  Both dropdownlists are in the same update panel.  However, this is also the case in the test form I created for testing and everything works fine there.

Comment: Show your aspx markup and the relevant code-behind.

Comment: Please show your code including relevant code-beside.

Comment: Do a search for selectedindexchanged in your code, it will be registered somewhere. Unfortunately without seeing the code, we can't say where.

Comment: @Mr.Young code-beside? that's new... :-)

Comment: @Steve, yup it's been that way since 2003. With the introduction of the partial keyword C# driven webpage are referred to as "code-beside" since there is a partial class someplace else. This is off-topic to his question. But you can learn about it on this StackOverFlow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924426/difference-between-code-beside-and-code-behind

Comment: You might have the Event registered someplace in the aspx markup. I would also search for OnSelectedIndexChanged or OnSelectedItemChanged.

Comment: @Mr.Young Oh well I never stop to learn something new here.

Comment: I'm actually adding both dropdownlists programatically so it wouldnt be in codebehind

Comment: So you ARE adding these IN the code-behind and not in the mark-up. Can we see the second drop down list code? Also what happens on page_load or in the constructor? I see you have AutoPostBack enabled and there is some weird things that could happen during this event.

Comment: @Mason: What happens if you don't assign an ID to both DropDownLists at all? What is `dex`, is it possible that you mix the ID's across postbacks? Where are you creating them  (in the life-cycle) and where do you add them to the page?

Comment: oops, I meant to say it wouldnt be in markup, sorry. Also, I need to keep the IDs for stuff I do in the ddlset_SelectedIndexChanged method.  dex is just a counter I'm using to keep ID's distinct.  The page_load is very long but if you are looking for something specific I could post that.

Comment: I create the dropdownlists in page_init and add them to the page there as well

Comment: @Mr.Young: However, i've never heard of that term and you'll find it nowhere on MSDN even if it should be the replacement of code-behind since .NET2. Even now   only two page models are mentioned on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb(v=vs.100).aspx): Single-File and Code-Behind. _"The code-behind model used in the .NET Framework version 2.0 is different than the one used in earlier versions."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Wierd, it's all over asp.net. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services . It's really the same thing. Like 'Metro' and 'Live Tiles' ;-)

Comment: @Mason How do you evaluate what was posted back to the server. Have you tried registering both event handlers and setting break-points in each? Perhaps both are firing.

Comment: There is only one event handler and it's only registered to ddlset1